# How to send APNs push messages using APNs Auth Key and standard CLI tools?

Tags: apple-push-notifications

Apple recently added a new authentication method to APNS ( [Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39671902/apple-push-notification-authentication-key-sandbox-production)).

[image]

The downloaded key is a `.p8` file with a private key:

```
$ cat APNSAuthKey_3HHEB343FX.p8
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBH...Already.Revoked...lHEjCX1v51W
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am using APNs messages using the old method - adding them to keychain, asking for a certificate and using OpenSSL to send messages to `gateway.production.push.apple.com:2195`.

**How do I send push notifications using standard CLI Linux tools (OpenSSL, Python etc.) using the new format?**

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you have curl with HTTP/2 support and openssl with ECDSA support installed on your machine, you can use the following script to test push notifications using an APNs Auth Key:

```
#!/bin/bash

deviceToken=b27371497b85611baf9052b4ccfb9641ab7fea1d01c91732149c99cc3ed9342f

authKey="./APNSAuthKey_ABC1234DEF.p8"
authKeyId=ABC1234DEF
teamId=TEAM123456
bundleId=com.example.myapp
endpoint=https://api.development.push.apple.com

read -r -d '' payload <<-'EOF'
{
   "aps": {
      "badge": 2,
      "category": "mycategory",
      "alert": {
         "title": "my title",
         "subtitle": "my subtitle",
         "body": "my body text message"
      }
   },
   "custom": {
      "mykey": "myvalue"
   }
}
EOF

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------

base64() {
   openssl base64 -e -A | tr -- '+/' '-_' | tr -d =
}

sign() {
   printf "$1" | openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -sign "$authKey" | base64
}

time=$(date +%s)
header=$(printf '{ "alg": "ES256", "kid": "%s" }' "$authKeyId" | base64)
claims=$(printf '{ "iss": "%s", "iat": %d }' "$teamId" "$time" | base64)
jwt="$header.$claims.$(sign $header.$claims)"

curl --verbose \
   --header "content-type: application/json" \
   --header "authorization: bearer $jwt" \
   --header "apns-topic: $bundleId" \
   --data "$payload" \
   $endpoint/3/device/$deviceToken
```

**NOTE:** I use a slight variation of this script for testing on **macOS with homebrew** versions of curl and openssl: http://thrysoee.dk/apns/

Apple now have documentation for *this* method to [Send a Push Notification Using a Token](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools#3694579).

Comment: @JessThrysoee Your "slight variation" works like a **CHAMP**. Thanks for posting your hard work for all to see, it's people like you that keep the community juiced +1

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful script. On my Mac, I had to add the "--with-nghttp2" option to install curl with http2 support (as the home-brew curl doesn't currently seem to have the http2 support by default):          
   brew install curl --with-nghttp2. 
        
(or as I already had curl installed:  
     brew reinstall curl --with-nghttp2  )

Then on the curl command in the script, I added the option:  

   --http2  

and script works well. Thank you.

Comment: I keep getting "unable to load key file"

Comment: As a note, curl must be compiled with OpenSSL and nghttp2 if using brew: `brew install --with-openssl --with-nghttp2 curl`

Comment: I am getting error when execute command sh apns.sh on terminal

Comment: > Content-Length: 247
> 
* upload completely sent off: 247 out of 247 bytes
Warning: Binary output can mess up your terminal. Use "--output -" to tell 
Warning: curl to output it to your terminal anyway, or consider "--output 
Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
* Failed writing body (0 != 33)
* Closing connection 0

Comment: Homebrew recently removed install options for curl so install curl-openssl `brew install curl-openssl` and then in the script change curl `curl=/usr/local/opt/curl-openssl/bin/curl`

Comment: @Neil I have updated the macOS script with your homebrew curl-openssl change. Thanks.

Comment: iOS 13, swift 5. Works perfectly!! THANKYOU

Answer (score 13):

You can send push notification by NODE JS using Apple Push Notification Authentication Key (Sandbox & Production). There is a tutorial provided by Elad Nava in [this link](https://eladnava.com/send-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-using-xcode-8-and-swift-3/)

This tutorial has all steps of creating the  Apple Push Notification Authentication Key and setting up a local server to run Node JS code for sending push notification. You can run the code in your local machine and test the push notification.

Hope this will help.

Comment: This is life saver! It's so elegant!

Answer (score 6):

Voilà in PHP what it looks like with curl and HTTP/2. This script return the 200 ok status code along with the generated token id.

```
// THE FINAL SCRIPT WITHOUT DEPENDENCIES!!! ...except curl with http2
$device_token = "a0abd886etc...";
//echo $key;
$kid      = "YOURKEYID";
$teamId   = "YOURTEAMID";
$app_bundle_id = "your.app.bundle";
$base_url = "https://api.development.push.apple.com";

$header = ["alg" => "ES256", "kid" => $kid];
$header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));

$claim = ["iss" => $teamId, "iat" => time()];
$claim = base64_encode(json_encode($claim));

$token = $header.".".$claim;
// key in same folder as the script
$filename = "KeyFromApple.p8";
$pkey     = openssl_pkey_get_private("file://{$filename}");
$signature;
openssl_sign($token, $signature, $pkey, 'sha256');
$sign = base64_encode($signature);

$jws = $token.".".$sign;

$message = '{"aps":{"alert":"You are welcome.","sound":"default"}}';

function sendHTTP2Push($curl, $base_url, $app_bundle_id, $message, $device_token, $jws) {

    $url = "{$base_url}/3/device/{$device_token}";
    // headers
    $headers = array(
        "apns-topic: {$app_bundle_id}",
        'Authorization: bearer ' . $jws
    );
    // other curl options
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $message,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1
    ));
    // go...
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        throw new Exception("Curl failed: " .  curl_error($curl));
    }
    print_r($result."\n");
    // get response
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl);
    return $status;
}
// open connection
$curl = curl_init();
sendHTTP2Push($curl, $base_url, $app_bundle_id, $message, $device_token, $jws);
```

Comment: you're welcome. I had a hard time make it works without dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided by Nicolas Manzini, while helpful, did not fully work for me. I also wanted to use command line curl.  In particular, reading in the .p8 file was causing some problems.  A modified version:

```
<?php

$teamid = 'YOURTEAMID';
$keyid = 'A464FN6T93';     // in the name of the file downloaded from Apple Certs

// since it is a universal key, I wanted this in a location accessible to several accounts
$keyFile = '/path/to/file/AuthKey_A464FN6T93.p8';

$privateKey = openssl_pkey_get_private('file://' . $keyFile);

if (! $privateKey) {
    die('could not find: ' . $keyFile);
}

$header = ['alg' => 'ES256', 'kid' => $keyid];
$header = base64_encode(json_encode($header));

$claim = ['iss' => $teamid, 'iat' => time()];
$claim = base64_encode(json_encode($claim));

$tok = $header . '.' . $claim;

// pass in empty $signature, 2nd line below fills it
$signature = '';
$result = openssl_sign($tok, $signature, $privateKey, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);      //  'sha256'
if (! $result) {
    die('unable to create signature');
}

$sign = base64_encode($signature);

openssl_free_key($privateKey);

$jwt = $tok . '.' . $sign;

foreach($tokens as $token) {
    $cmd = '\
    /usr/local/bin/curl -v \
    -d \'{"aps":{"alert":{"title":"Notification Title","body":"You are being notified!"},"sound":"default"}}\' \
    -H "apns-topic: com.app.bundle.id" \
    -H "authorization: bearer ' . $jwt . '" \
    -H "content-type:application/json" \
    --http2 \
    https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/' . $token . ' 2>&1';    // ending w/ 2>&1, sends output to $output

    exec($cmd, $output, $return);

    if ($return != 0) {
        // be notified of error
    }
    else {
        foreach($output as $line) {
            if (strpos($line, 'apns-id')) {
                $apns = $line;
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: what if i want to send to multiple devices the same message, can i use an array of tokens?